Extract SET var = func(x, y, z); from code, possibly with newlines
I have to do a recursive search for a word and then select the line/lines until the ).
My file looks like below and the output is mentioned below.
SET var1 = FormatValue(A1,B1,B2); 
SET var2 = FormatValue(X1, 
X2, 
X3); 
DEFINE VAR3; 
SET var4 = FormatValue(z1,z2,
z3);

i want to search for all lines containing 'set' and also up until the closing bracket ')' I want the output to be
SET var1 = FormatValue(A1,B1,B2); 
SET var2 = FormatValue(X1, X2, X3); 
SET var4 = FormatValue(z1,z2, z3); 


your output doesn't match your description. why is there a trailing semicolon? Also set != SET

what happens if SET appears elsewhere (eg. variable name, part of another word, inside a string, etc)?

Using GNU awk:
awk '{gsub("\n","")}$1=="SET"' RS='; *' ORS=';\n' file

gsub removes all newlines in the record delimited by a semi-colon ; (as set by RS).
Only record starting with SET are printed.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
SET var1 = FormatValue(A1,B1,B2); 
SET var2 = FormatValue(X1, 
X2, 
X3); 
DEFINE VAR3; 
SET var4 = FormatValue(z1,z2,
z3);

then
awk '/^SET/{p=1}p{if(/\)/){print;p=0}else{printf "%s",$0}}' file.txt

gives output
SET var1 = FormatValue(A1,B1,B2); 
SET var2 = FormatValue(X1, X2, X3); 
SET var4 = FormatValue(z1,z2,z3);

Explanation: if line starts with SET I set p to 1, if p is set I check if line contains ) and if it does I print line as is and set p to 0 otherwise I printf whole line ($0) which result in output line without trailing newline, so it could be continued.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -n '/^SET /{:a;/)/!{N;ba};s/\n/ /g;p}' file

Use the -n option to suppress implicit printing as this is a filter operation.
If a line beginning with the string SET then:

Look for a closing paren and if not append the next line and go again.
Replace each newline by a space.
Print the result.


Using TXR:
$ txr set.txr data
SET var1 = FormatValue(A1,B1,B2);
SET var2 = FormatValue(X1,  X2,  X3);
SET var4 = FormatValue(z1,z2, z3);

Code in set.txr:
@(repeat)
@  (freeform " ")
SET @var = @fun(@args);
@  (do (put-line `SET @var = @fun(@args);`))
@(end)

Normally, the TXR Pattern language is oriented toward multi-line text. The freeform directive changes the discipline. The pattern match which follows is matched against an altered version of the input in which lines are folded into one giant line. The optional string argument specifies the line terminating sequence, which defaults to \n (newline).
After the pattern match which follows freeform matches part of the virtual line, the unmatched portion of the virtual line is converted back to multiple lines; subsequent pattern matching is back in multi-line discipline.
